# Increasing Heap memory in Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I am handling a huge data file, with 5 million lines and file size is 468m.b The program requires too much of iteration and creation of hash tables.

I have increased xmx in .ini file of Eclipse to 1812, also, in run, run configuration, I have set variable for my Program more than 1500. However the heap status shows:
heap size:117M of total 127 max: 1621 mark < none >;

I need help in this. Can I increase the total?
Please reply.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F) out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on you main prog then select  Run AS --> run configuration
select "argument" tab
In VM arguments set memory as per your requirement (-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m)
and then run

Comment: I have set -XmX as 1024 in argument, it doesn't increase the total? Why?

Comment: @ - Josh M, I have read it many number of times, but it doesn't allocate the same. Heap memory in Eclipse show the increased one, but it never uses that. I am wondering why?

Comment: They're entirely separate processes and instructions. @upog said to edit your application's Launch Configuration, *not* the eclipse.ini file.  The INI file affects *Eclipse*, not your application.

Comment: @-nitnd
Ohh k. I will edit as what has been said by upog and see the difference. Thank you.

Comment: Vote up my answer, if it helped you

Comment: Yep. As @upog says, it's __your program__ that you want to give more heap to -- not Eclipse. And give him an upvote.

Comment: @ upog and thomas W, I am new to stackoverflow and do not know how to vote up. I tried clicking on left arrow adjacent to your reply but it seems I cannot do that until I have 15 reputation.

Also, I did what upog said, but I am still in that problem. Cannot we increase the TOTAL? I made -Xms1024 and -Xmx 2284, but now the total is 204M